# How to display the childs of a parent in a listview using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

i'm trying to display the children tags of a parent of xml file in a listview using jquery dynamically.

```
$(xml).find('section[order="' + order + '"] content').each(function () {
     var content = $(this).text();
var section = $(this).find('section').attr("name");
 $("#section_list").append(section+'<li><a href="#" class="style1"><h2>' + content + ' </h2></a></li> ');
$("#section_list").listview("refresh");
});
```

This is my code i'm getting the child tags in a listview but the parent tag is getting for every child.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <sections>
    <section count="6" name="Alphabets" order="1">
      <content order="1">A</content>
      <content order="2">B</content>
      <content order="3">C</content>
      <content order="4">D</content>
      <content order="5">E</content>
      <content order="6">F</content>
    </section>
    <section count="4" name="Numbers" order="2">
      <content order="7">1</content>
      <content order="8">2</content>
      <content order="9">3</content>
      <content order="10">4</content>
    </section>
</sections>
```

The desire output is

Alphabets

A

B

C

D

E

F

Numbers

1

2

3

4

"ABCDEF" and "1234" should be display in listview and parent tags should display as above.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (var order = 1; order < 3; order++) {
        $('xml').find('section[order="' + order + '"]').each(function () {
            //iterate by section
            var sectionName = $(this).attr("name");
            //Add Section Name to the list
            $("#section_list").append(sectionName);
            $(this).children().each(function () {
                //iterate by section/content
                //for each content tag under section add a li element
                $("#section_list").append('<li><a href="#" class="style1"><h2>' + $(this).text() + ' </h2></a></li> ');
            });
            //$("#section_list").listview("refresh");
        });
    }
```

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5vUp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for answering..but i already tried in this way not working..and i think in your answer "var content = $(this).text();" is missing..

Comment: updated and made a fiddle. I am treating xml as a html tag right now but that can be easily modified in your code. Also I am just using a ul instead of listview for demo purpose.

Comment: i tried its working fine but after extending my code it is not working...i'm using listview for the childs..Thanks in Advance

Comment: well you can always post revised code and troubleshoot the new problems. Or if the solutions so far have you satisfied I would request you to accept the answer and consider this question closed.

Comment: Sorry for late reply codetantrik...its working but when my code is added with other features its not working..for that i used listdividers for category wise display but no use...if any suggestions is there..Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should close this and post the new problems in a fresh question.